# Limit as x approaches infinity of $x^{-x}$?

Tags: calculus

I am really confused by this question. When I put the question into wolfram alpha I get 0, but when I compute it I get $$e^1$$. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I write the $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}x^{-x}$$ as

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}e^{-{x\ln x}}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}- x \ln x $$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{-\ln x}{x^{-1}}$$

and I end up with e. I am not sure.

Comment: You're good until $-x\ln(x)$. How you got to the line beneath that is above me.

Answer (score 1):

Expression can be simplified $x^{-x}$) as ${1 \over x^x}$.
$$\lim_{x\to∞} \frac1{x^x} = 0$$.
Then enforce the limit and probably you would get the limit as $0$
See the basis is that your question is a general form of $0^{\infty}$ which is not an *indeterminate* *form*.
You have treated the limit as *indeterminate* *form* in your
question . Probably that is the reason you are not getting the required answer. Directly enforce limit in case of no indeterminate forms.

Comment: Alternatively apply sandwich theorem with $0<x^{-x}<x^{-1}.$

Answer (score 1):

For $x>1$, $0<x^{-x}<x^{-1}.$

Apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln x=+\infty$

since

$\forall x>e$, $\ln x>1$, so $x\ln x>x$

Comment: the denominator is 1/x not x

Comment: How'd you get that? No steps...

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the expression inside your limit ($x^{-x}$) as ${1 \over x^x}$.
$$\lim_{x\to∞} \frac1{x^x} = 0$$.

Answer (score 0):

You found
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{-x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{-{x\ln x}},
\tag1$$
which is correct.
If you can then find the limit $L$ of the exponent, you can
plug that into $e^L$ to evaluate $(1)$.

Next you have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} - x \ln x = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{-\ln x}{x^{-1}}.$$
Again, this is fine.

Abusing the notation in the usual way, as $x\to+\infty$
we have $-\ln \infty = -\infty$ and $(+\infty)^{-1} = +0.$
So you have $\frac{-\infty}{+0},$ which is an indeterminate form
(not $1$) if we don't consider the direction 
in which $x^{-1}$ approaches $0,$
or you consider that the denominator actually is always positive
and you have $-\infty.$
And $e^{-\infty} = 0,$ which is the correct answer.